# using wgrib2 to convert grib2 to netcdf: problem in batch

Tags: powershell, netcdf

wgrib2 works well in powershell with code:

```
.\\wgrib2 F:\\C20191001-20191031\\20191001\\INPUT.GRB2 -netcdf OUTPUT.nc
```

but the problem is I need process all the GRB2 files under this 20191001 folder.
I tried codes like this:

```
$dir = dir F:\\C20191001-20191031\\test  *.GRB2
foreach($_ in $dir)
{
.\\wgrib2   $_  -netcdf  $_+'.nc'   
}
```

But it does not work. Error messages:

```
*** FATAL ERROR: missing input file .\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dllZ_NAFP_C_BABJ_20191001000911_P_CLDAS_RT_CHN_0P05_HOR-TCDC-2019100100.GRB2 *** 
*** FATAL ERROR: missing input file .\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dllZ_NAFP_C_BABJ_20191001001009_P_CLDAS_RT_CHN_0P05_HOR-RHU-2019100100.GRB2 ***
```

The `api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll`is a .dll file enclosed in this wgribs tools.

Comment: Please _edit the question_ and explain what "it does not work" means. Do you get an error message? What does it say? Something unexpected happens? The error message, if any, often contains clues about what's wrong.

Comment: *** FATAL ERROR: missing input file .\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dllZ_NAFP_C_BABJ_20191001000911_P_CLDAS_RT_CHN_0P05_HOR-TCDC-2019100100.GRB2 ***


*** FATAL ERROR: missing input file .\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dllZ_NAFP_C_BABJ_20191001001009_P_CLDAS_RT_CHN_0P05_HOR-RHU-2019100100.GRB2 ***

Comment: I got error messages like this.↑

Comment: So, what are valid file names? Do you have a file that starts with `api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll`? Add this information to the question body. _Do not add a comment_; comments are hard to read when there's data and to understand the question one shouldn't need to read the comment thread as well.